# How to create a java.util.Calendar instance at epoch time?

Tags: calendar

Is there any existing way to get a Calendar populated with time at epoch using Calendar API's other than explicitly setting them at epoch? All I was able to do was to get the current time.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is no pre defined constructor or factory method to do this, but it is fairly simple:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(0);
```